# How do I export/import a subset of data resulting of a SELECT

Tags: pgadmin

This is driving me nuts. I'm using PGAdmin and I want to export a subset of data from my production environment into my local environment. I have both configured in PGAdmin.

If I use the "Export" option to export the entire production table, I can import it back into my local database without a problem.

However, if I first do a SELECT statement on the production database and then click the "Save results to file" option and chose csv (the only option I have btw), this results in a file that I cannot import in my local database.

And I have cryptic error after cryptic error. Either some jsonb value is not in correct format, or some values were exported as NULL and it does not like that...

I cannot entirely export some of the tables in production because of their sheer size. And I am only really interested in some records. So how do I do this? And how such basic functionality is totally broken in a tool like this?

Thanks ahead